# LoadRunner - Doubts on Requirements

Tags: performance

Our team is planning to implement LoadRunner for performance testing.Please clarify me on these requirement issues?

1. In how many systems can we install a licensed LoadRunner? Or onto a single system?
2. For Controller, Virtul User Generator and Load Generator, do we need seperate machines or it can be in a single machine?

Answer (score 1):

You are in the midst of a change in the LoadRunner licensing universe.  First a historical view and next a view from what is now.

Historical.
Prior to 8.0

- You purchase a controller license which includes a single license for VUGEN and Analysis.
- You may install as many load generators as you wish.
- The controller is node locked to a single host and must be deregistered to be moved to a new host, which involves Mercury support
- Best practice says that your controller and your load generators are not the same machine (this is tool independent for all performance testing tools).
- It is highly likely that you use VUGEN and Analysis on a machine other than the controller.
- Additional copies of VUGEN and Analysis are available for purchase in singles or groups of five and ten
- Virtual Users are tied to a controller license
- Monitors are licensed individually

8.0 through 11.5x (Dec 2013)

- You purchase a controller license which includes a promiscuous license for multiple copies of VUGEN and Analysis tied to your controller.
- You may install as many load generators as you wish.
- The controller is node locked to a single host and must be deregistered to be moved to a new host, which involves HP support
- Best practice says that your controller and your load generators are not the same machine (this is tool independent for all performance testing tools).
- It is highly likely that you use VUGEN and Analysis on a machine other than the controller.
- Once your controller license expires you must also remove the other components which are tied to the license, namely VUGEN and Analysis
- Virtual Users are tied to a controller license
- Monitors are included, including a 500 point SiteScope instance for test use only

With 2014

- Controllers are not charged for components.  Neither is VUGEN, Analysis or Load Generators
- (My understanding from a phone call yesterday where I have not seen the full license agreement) You may install as many copies of each component as you wish.
- Virtual Users are the chargeable component and these are still tied to a single controller instance.   So you may install 500 controllers, but only one may actually have virtual users attached to it.  No shared virtual user pools unless you move to Performance Center
- Monitor status unknown.  Ask your VAR or HP Rep for details.

Under no circumstances for any performance testing too would a complete monolithic installation on one machine be considered best practices (holds for LoadRunner, SilkPerformer, RationalPerformanceTester, JMeter, OPENSTA, SOASTA, ...).   For load generation you want all load generation to happen on hosts independent of your controller and you would want at least three load generators in play, two for primary load and one as a control host (single virtual user of each type).   Three may be the minimum number of load generators, but it is far from the maximum, which may number in the dozens depending upon your needs.